# How to set XSL property on inherited core search results webpart

Tags: web-part, search-results

I have created a custom Search results web part by inheriting from coreresultswebpart.  I would like to override the default XSL with some modified XSL in my project instead of having to set the XSL using the web part properties on the site.

I have already added a few custom properties to my custom webpart and found a [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.dataformwebpart.xsl%28v=office.14%29.aspx) discussing the DataFormWebPart.Xsl Property.  Just not sure how to take my modified XSL and set it to that property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your webpart constructor just set the property there.

```
public MyCustomWebpart()
{
     this.Xsl = "<xml></xml>";
}
```